# How to provide delete authorization to certain user profiles ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I want to give permission to certain user profiles (i.e. Administrators, Managers which I already have it in DB) to delete certain records in DB if they press the delete button in my ASP.NET web application page. Can someone help me on this? Or provide me useful resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to handle user roles. One of them is [forms authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.140).aspx). It makes role management very easy and you won't have to spend much time on it once you get it set up. [More info here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb(v=vs.140).aspx).

If you wanted to set up your own role management system, you could just add a column to your `Users` table called `Role` and set visibility of controls based on the value of `Role`.

If it were me, I would add a class called `CurrentUser` having the properties from your `Users` table (including `Role`). Your `Insert()`, `Update()`, and `Delete()` methods might then look something like this:

```
if (CurrentUser.Role == "Admin" || CurrentUser.Role == "Manager")
{
    // Allow insert, update, or delete to process
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your information. To be more clear, I have set of user profiles in my SQL Server table. I want only couple of those profiles to be granted access to delete certain records in another table.